# Existence or construction of a sequence of orthogonal matrices with three properties

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes

This is a problem that I encountered during my research, and I have spent a good amount of time on it without success. So I am reaching out for help ....
Any pointers or suggestions are appreicated!

**The problem**: 
Let $m\geq8$ be an even integer and $\varepsilon,\alpha\in\left(  0,1\right)
$ be two fixed constants. For each $m$ large enough, construct or an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{T}_{m}=\left(  \gamma_{ij}\right)
$ such that

1. Each $\gamma_{ij} \neq 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq j \leq m$;
2. The following inequality holds
   $$
   1 -\varepsilon \geq \min_{\left[  \alpha m\right]  +1\leq i\leq m}\sum_{j=\left[  \alpha m\right]
   +1}^{m}\gamma_{ij}^{2}\geq\varepsilon,
   $$
   where $\left[  x\right]  $ denotes the integer part of $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

   3. Put the last $m-[\alpha m]$ columns (by keeping the order of the column indices) of $\mathbf{T}_{m}$ into a matrix $\mathbf{R}$. Then, for the matrix $\mathbf{R}$ and a constant $\beta \in (0,\alpha)$, pick a submatrix $\mathbf{G}$ of size $[\beta m] \times (m-[\alpha m])$ from the first $[\alpha m]$ rows of $\mathbf{R}$. Also pick a submatrix of $\mathbf{H}$ of size $[\beta m] \times (m-[\alpha m])$ from the last $m-[\alpha m]$ rows of $\mathbf{R}$. Then, no such $\beta$ exists such that $\mathbf{G} = - \mathbf{H}$ or $\mathbf{G} = \mathbf{H}$
      for any  $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ thus picked.

The inequality in display requires that the lower right block of size $[\left(
1-\alpha\right)  m]$ of $\mathbf{T}_{m}$ has rows of Euclidean norms bounded
from below by $\varepsilon$ and from above by $1 -\varepsilon$ regardless of what $m$ is. It becomes highly nontrivial to obtain such a $\mathbf{T}_{m}$.

**Constructive proof for such a sequence $\left\{  \mathbf{T}_{m}\right\}  _{m\geq8,m\in2\mathbb{N}}$ is preferred.**

**Note** I edited the problem. Now a third restriction is added. Without the third restriction, Walsh matrices pointed by Dr. Bill Johnson satisfy the rest two.

**Background** I encountered this problem when I was trying to contruct a counterexample to a general claim made in a published paper on the convergence of a stochastic process related to high-dimensional multiple testing.

**My attempts** The simple reflection trick to construct an orthogonal matrix is not able to obtain $\mathbf{T}_m$ for which the displayed inequality holds. I also tried (a) using the Haar measure to show the existence of such an $\mathbf{T}_m$ with positive probability but it essentially reduces to the same problem described above; (b) tried orthogonal matrix induced by dicrete cosine transform, but it can not achieve the uniformity needed in the displayed inequality.

Comment: Use Walsh matrices.

Comment: @Stefan Kohl: how to add a top-level tag?@Bill Johnson: I see; only need to normalize the Walsh matrices. Thank you both!

Comment: Probably you don't mean what you wrote down as a formula (your verbal description doesn't match this either). To get the *minimum* between the required bounds, just take a lower right block that is diagonal, with all $1$'s, except for one $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, and now it's trivial to build a unitary matrix out of this (it can be diagonal except for two non-diagonal entries).

Comment: @ChristianRemling: sharp eyes! After I posted the orignal problem, where it was also required that $\gamma_{ij} \neq 0$ for each $i,j$, I removed this requirement since I thought it may be hard to find such an orthogonal matrix for each such $m$. Then Dr. Johnson pionted out the Walsh matrices, which satisfy both two requirements. Now that I have read your comments, and I added this requirement back.

Comment: @Chee: I don't think requiring $\gamma_{ij}\not= 0$ changes much, I'm pretty confident a small perturbation (within $O(m)$) of my example (say) will have this property generically.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: In fact I agree with you on th existence. However, it is the explicit construction (outsize the Walsh matrices) that is very difficult. My intuition is that the Haar measure should assign positive mass on the set of all such orthogonal matrices, which then implies the existence. However, without rigorous proof, it is just a guess; without a systematic construction, we still do not fully understand these matrices.